# Performing async operations that are guaranteed to execute within an IIS web site, even if an app pool is recycled

Tags: .net, iis, asynchronous, threadpool

Certain actions that my web site's users carry out result in the sending of emails. The code that sends emails can block for a while, so I want to do this off their HTTP request handler's thread.

Currently I'm using something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {
    try
    {
        email.Send();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("Error sending email", ex);
    }
});
```

For the most part, this works. However the web site runs in a hosted environment where the app pool can be recycled.

Every once in a while I don't receive an email that should have been sent, and I suspect that this work item on the threadpool's queue is being dropped during application pool recycling.

How can I perform an ansync operation like this and guarantee that it will complete in such a case?

Comment: what version of .net and iis are you using?

Comment: @devundef I'm hosting my site with winhost.com, who are running IIS 7.0 / .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your application runs in integrated mode, you can register your mail dispatcher service within the host environment. The host will notify your service *before* a recycling is done. 
The host will call your implementation of `IRegisteredObject.Stop` exactly 2 times. On the first call the host gives you the opportunity to finish the job. If the timeout is reached and your service has not removed itself from the host, then another call is made​, but this time only to notify that the recycling will be made with or without the consent of the service.

This is an example (not tested) of how you can implement the Stop() method:

```
public class MailDispatchService : IRegisteredObject
{
    private AutoResetEvent _processQueueEvt = new AutoResetEvent();
    private ConcurrentQueue<MailMessage> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<MailMessage>();
    private Thread _dispatcherThread;
    private volatile bool _enabled = true;

    #region Implementation of IRegisteredObject

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        if (_dispatcherThread != null && _dispatcherThread.IsAlive)
        {
            // it's not an immediate stop, we can wait for the queue to empty
            if (!immediate)
            {
                // stop accepting new items in the send queue...
                _enabled = false;
                // awake dispatcher thread, so it can quit if the queue is empty
                _processQueueEvt.Set();
                // and wait for a while but not forever.
                _dispatcherThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            }
            else
            {
                // host env will recycle now, nothing to do...
                _dispatcherThread.Abort();
            }
        }
        // remove the service from host
        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }

    #endregion

    public void Start()
    {
        _dispatcherThread = new Thread(ProcessQueue);
        _dispatcherThread.Start();
    }

    private void ProcessQueue()
    {
        while (_enabled)
        {
            _processQueueEvt.WaitOne();
            MailMessage message;
            while (_queue.TryDequeue(out message)) { /* send mail ...*/}
        }
    }

    public void DispatchEmail(MailMessage message)
    {
        if (!_enabled) throw new Exception("....");
        _queue.Enqueue(message);
        _processQueueEvt.Set();
    }
}
```

Start the service and register it on the host.

```
var mailService = new MailDispatchService();
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(mailService);
mailService.Start();

var message = new MailMessage();
mailService.DispatchEmail(message);
```

Comment: This answer is very good. One could even factor out the shutdown detection code into a separate, reusable class.

Comment: This looks great. I'll have to find out whether I'm running in integrated mode.

Comment: According to [HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.usingintegratedpipeline.aspx), I am using the integrated pipeline. This is great news!

Comment: `_dispatcherThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`

But what to do when there are a lot of emails or an SMTP server is not available? The `_queue` is not persistent and does not give guarantee that each email will be sent anyway, even after application restart.

To provide such guarantee you need to use persistent queues and reliable fetching to process items even if a worker thread was aborted due to timeouts (this one or the ASP.NET ShutdownTimeout which defaults to 30 seconds) after restarting the application.

Comment: In this case the OP doesn't have the MSMQ available. This service could be improved to write down the queue on the sql server and then pick from there one message at a time, updating some flag after send the message. Registering the service within the Host would prevent the interruption of the service in the middle of the process of sending that 1 message. But then you'll have to deal with the case when you have more than one instance running (more servers or on recycling cicles)

Answer (score 2):

Best option here would be to use a persistent message queue or service bus. Your app writes email request to queue, queue handler (which could be your web app) reads queue and processes message. If things die, the persistence angle kicks in -- the messages hang around until they can be processed.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my original question, but I am not in control of the box. It's a hosted environment where I cannot use MSMQ or anything like that. Just plain old IIS 7 and SQL 2008. As @Filip suggests, I could implement such a queue on top of SQL, but there's no guarantee it would be robust anyway, as I believe my thread would be aborted, meaning I couldn't make a reliable transaction around the sending of the email and updating of SQL.